# Laravel: Filtering users where multiple tags are present

Tags: laravel, search, eloquent, filtering, relationship

All users on my page can have multiple tags. Let's assume these tags are labeled "A", "B" and "C".

Through my search function, I click on the "A" to filter out only users, that have the "A" tag. Now, I can click on "B" to add to the filtering, so that I only want to retrieve the users that have both "A" and "B".

This means that the users, that only have ONE tag applied (either "A" or "B") will be excluded from the filtering results.

For the sake of simplicity, there are three tables: users, tags, tag_binds

```
users
- id
- name

tags
 - id
 - name ("A", "B", "C" etc.)

tag_binds
- id
- tag_id
- user_id
```

How do I achieve this in Eloquent?

Answer (score 0):

Use `HasManyThrough` Like this in `user` table:

User Model:

```
public function tags() {
      return $this->hasManyThrough(
         'App\Tags',
         'App\TagBinds',
         'user_id',
         'id',
         'id',
         'tag_id'
      );
    }
```

Retrive the data by:

```
$searchdata = ['A','B']; //keep it as an array
if(count($searchdata) > 1) {
    $data = User::with('tags')
                      ->orWhereHas('tags', function($q) use ($searchdata){
                            $q->whereIn('name', $searchdata);
                      })->get();

} else {
    $data = User::with('tags')
                      ->orWhereHas('tags', function($q) use ($searchdata){
                            $q->where('name', 'LIKE', '%' . $searchdata[0] . '%');
                       })->get();

}
```

Let Me know if it helps you !

Comment: Thank you. I tried going with your suggestion. I think it's somewhat the correct approach, however I am still getting User1 with only "A" as a tag. User2, however, has both "A" and "B", and it's only these users I want to retrieve.

Comment: does this satisfy your desired ans or is there some problem?

Comment: What I'm looking for is to ONLY retrieve the users that have the exact selected combinations. For example, if I select "A" and "B" for my filter, then the query must only select those users that have at least those two tags. So it's basically "Select users that have tag 'A' AND tag 'B'". Hope this clarifies my problem :-)

And to continue, if I select "C" afterwards, then I only want to retrieve users with A + B + C tags.